# Why is this simple set of joins returning an unexpectedly wrapped result?

Tags: python, join

I was trying to join three (hex code) digits together as one string and something strange happened.

```
a='00'
b='01'
c='ff'

abc = ''.join(a).join(b).join(c)
print(abc)
```

and I get the result:

> `f0001f` instead of the expected `0001ff`

What could be causing this?

Comment: ''.join() is your separator for the next join and so on

Comment: `join()` treats its parameter as an iterable. In your example (ie your `a`, `b` and `c`) the parameter is a collection of two items which it places either side of the string it is operating on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see it step by step

```
''.join('00') => 0 '' 0 => 00
'00'.join('01') => 0 00 1 => 0001
'0001'.join('ff') => f 0001 f => f0001f
```

Comment: That’s the answer

Answer (score 3):

"join" joins all elements in a list with the string it was called on.

So

```
",".join(['a', 'b', 'c']) = "a,b,c"
```

So what you're actually doing in your code is

```
''.join('00') -> "00"
'00'.join('01') -> "0001"
'0001'.join('ff') -> "f0001f"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood what `join()` does.

`''.join(a)` will return `00` since it will join each char of a with the empty string, not doing anything.

However, the next call will be `'00'.join(b)` which will join each char of `b` with `00`, resulting in `0001`. Then, `'0001'.join(c)` will give you `f0001f` because it's joining the chars from `c` with `0001`

---

What you were looking for is probably this: `''.join([a, b, c])` which will join the three strings together with the empty string as its "separator".

Another option would be a simple `a + b + c`. This is less optimized but for strings that short it shouldn't matter at all!

Answer (score 1):

You can try (concatenation of strings. No need to `join`.):

```
>>> a='00'
>>> b='01'
>>> c='ff'
>>> a+b+c
'0001ff'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3.6 or newer you might use so-called f-strings to get desired output:

```
a='00'
b='01'
c='ff'
out=f'{a}{b}{c}'
print(out) #0001ff
```

If you wish know more about f-strings I suggest reading this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).